# Could a minimization problem be easily converted into a NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I am trying to fit data that is correlated, such that the $\chi^2 = (f(x_i,pars)-y_i)(Cov^{-1})_{ij}(f(x_j,pars)-y_j)$.
However, `NonlinearModelFit` only accepts diagonal weights. Of course, the obvious approach would be to use `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`.

However, I find that either method has an inferior performance as compared to `NonlinearModelFit`. In particular, and taking a diagonal covariance matrix to compare `NonlinearModelFit`  vs. `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`, I find that the minima found by the latter two methods are not as small as those found by NonlinearModelFit. Also, the time it takes is, at least, 10 times bigger.

The time performance of course gets worse when building the $\chi^2$ for the full covariance matrix, that I can handle so far only via `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`.

In principle, this might not be a problem if I only have to wait for a couple of minutes. However, since I have to repeat this fit around 8000 times for a MonteCarlo procedure, this becomes extemely important.

Any ideas how to use `NonlinearModelFit` to minimize a given $\chi^2$?

(**Edited below**)

As a MWE, the covariance matrix `MyCovSqMat`

```
MyCorr = {{1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.7, 1, 0.7, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.7, 1, 
    0.7}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1}};
MyErr = {0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9};
MyCovSqMat = 
  Table[MyCorr[[i, j]] MyErr[[i]] MyErr[[j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
```

Then data with noise (`MyData`) is generated for a linear function `2+3x`

```
MyNoise = 
  RandomReal[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0, 0}, MyCovMat], 1];
MyData = Table[{i, 2 + 3 i + MyNoise[[1, i]]}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

Then we could fit taking only the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix either through `NonlinearModelFit` or minimization methods:

```
NonlinearModelFit[MyData, a + b x, {a, b}, x, Weights -> MyErr^-2]
MyChiSq = 
  Sum[((a + b MyData[[i, 1]] - MyData[[i, 2]])/MyErr[[i]])^2, {i, 1, 
    4}];
FindMinimum[MyChiSq, {a, b}]
```

However, the full covariance matrix can only be handled through `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`:

```
MyInvCovSqMat = Inverse[MyCovSqMat];
MyFullChiSq = 
  Sum[(a + b MyData[[i, 1]] - MyData[[i, 2]]) MyInvCovSqMat[[i, 
      j]] (a + b MyData[[j, 1]] - MyData[[j, 2]]), {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 
    4}];
FindMinimum[MyFullChiSq, {a, b}]
```

However, what I would like is to minimize `MyFullChiSq` above via `NonlinearModelFit` due to its apparently superior performance in more complicated fits

**Solution**

Finally there was an easy fix following @Ulrich Neuman:

```
NonlinearModelFit[{1, 0}, MyFullChiSq x, {a, b}, x]
```

Comment: Please, present a data for your $\chi^2$. In other case your question is too general to answer it.

Comment: I understand, my particular case is complicated. I will try to find a MWE, that might also be useful for myself anyhow. 
In any case, essentially I would need to have some function that depends on n variables and that should be minimized bye means of ``NonlinearModelFit``

Comment: I have edited the post and included a MWE hoping my question is clearer

Comment: At least for the example you give, `NonlinearModelFit` takes twice the amount of time as `FindMinimum`.  Also, you don't get any measures of precision.  To assume that the covariance matrix is known but the regression parameters are not, is hard to believe.  I think a more realistic example is needed.

Comment: I understand, but that's not necessarily the case in more complicated examples, as I commented. Unfortunately, the inpout required is too long. 
Regarding the covariance matrix I mean that from the data, not the one for the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MWE we could examplary try to fit a circle to random data `xy`

```
xy = Table[(1 + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]) {Cos[phi], Sin[phi ]}, {phi, 
RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}, 100]}];
```

Add `0` to the data

```
xy0 = Map[Join[#, {0}] &, xy];
```

and fit for unknown radius `R`

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[xy0, (x^2 + y^2 - R^2)^2, R, {x, y}]
fit["BestFitParameters"](*{R -> 1.0008}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's not exactly what I need (it seems a standard NonlinearModelFit). Thanks anyhow! I will try to provide now a MWE

Comment: @paplo You try to minimize a functional>=0  depending  on `xi,yi,pars` , that's what I show in my answer!

Comment: I just edited my entry, hope it makes it clearer. The trick to add 0 and minimize it is a nice one! but, still, you have many data points, while I have a single function (say, ``MyFullChiSq`` above) that depends on some parameters and should be minimize (the 0 in this case might help, but I don't have a data set)

Comment: Ok I see how to fix it, that helped a lot in order to figure out the solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach (going back to at least 1935) for your linear model ($a+bx$) with a known covariance matrix is Generalized Least Squares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squareshttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares).

Directly programming this approach is far faster than using `NonlinearModelFit` and just as important you can obtain the covariance matrix for the estimates of the parameters.

Using `SeedRandom[12345];` and using your data generation approach we have

```
(x = Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, Length[MyData]], MyData[[All, 1]]}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Design matrix]

```
y = MyData[[All, 2]]
(* {4.209, 8.29689, 11.1309, 14.5286} *)
ΣInv = MyInvCovSqMat;
AbsoluteTiming[estimates = Inverse[(Transpose[x] . ΣInv . x)] . Transpose[x] . ΣInv . y]
(* {0.000058, {1.75184, 3.2576}} *)
(cov = Inverse[Transpose[x] . ΣInv . x]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Covariance matrix]

```
se = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
(* {0.949452, 0.356867} *)
```

This gives the same estimates of the coefficients as in your approach and as in @UlrichNeumann 's answer but with the added bonus of the essential covariance matrix for having some idea of the precision of the estimates.

In real life "knowing" the covariance matrix without error is at best wishful thinking.

Comment: However, my problem is far from linear, nor it can be linearized, and cannot be solved analytically as in linear model cases, that was just a MWE to illustrate my needs. 
Somehow, the simpler version (diagonal covariance matrix) is handled much faster by nonlinearmodelfit, that the FindMinimum, that a nonlinear problem requires.
Of course, the covariance matrix for the parameters is important, but in mycase will be handled through a MC procedure.

Comment: Then your example should be nonlinear as it didn't illustrate your needs.  You have a single solution in mind.  This forum can be great especially when someone isn't as restricted.  This is not to be critical but there's more out there than any of us thinks we know.  Finally, you currently don't have measures of precision which are essential to convinces others of your results (unless maybe you're doing some sort of bootstrap process).

Comment: Just as another check to make sure:  Should I assume that your model is not linear in the coefficients?  I ask because $y=a_0+a_2 e^x+a_3 x^3+a_4 \sin(x)$ is a linear model with respect to $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, and $a_4$ and therefore generalized least squares would be appropriate for such a model.